Space-opera movie with Galactica-like ship and battles, ending with final battle/ambush on earth orbit?
I estimate movie to be from 1985-1995. It had strong (old)BSG aura. I am almost sure its original language was English (I encountered it in dubbing). I remember it as having quite good special effects (as opposed to most of crappy ripoff movies). Plot was shallow but covered with enough explosions to be enjoyable.
At the beginning (aside of some weak plot) earth fleet carrier/battleship fights alien fighters in some sort of nebula, noticeable scene was when one pilot instead of performing classic landing rotated fighter 180 degrees and just slammed it on deck (Starbuck style).
In the meantime, one pilot yells at rookies that they will get rocket right in tail if they will try solo-fight against alien craft (due to their superior maneuverability?).
Overall plot focused on aliens trying to get hold on main computer on any ship to get earth coordinates. (Quantum-shift jump to safe/stable orbit?)
Somehow they manage to get aboard one battleship (otherwise unimportant for plot), although some officer tried to destroy computer he quickly learned that placing bulletproof glass in front of it without any way to access it was bad idea.
So evil green guys got address of Earth orbital parking and are preparing to crack it with brute force and sheer numbers.
In meantime our brave Galactica ripoff is trying to get back with warning, but of course they can't. So someone gets idea to make fighter jump through black hole (or other weird thing), some kid said to be "spacenoid" capable of doing wormhole jumps (I doubt they used this exact term) whines that he lost his amulet and can't make the jump so some cool guy character gives him his amulet (no one apparently knew cool guy was also special wormhole jumping guy). Bucket or two of emotions later warning is delivered and earth fleet just camps outside of orbital parking zone and just blasts every alien that teleports there. Fin.
Final scene looked more like open ending, as it was just one of battles in long interstellar war.

I am pretty sure you're describing Wing Commander (1999).  The people who could make space jumps by heart/instinct are called "Pilgrims".
